# デプロイ時のプリコンパイルエラー

Tags: ruby, デプロイ

railsアプリをデプロイしたいのですが最後の段階でプリコンパイルエラーが出て先に進めません。
こちらのコマンド入力しました

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

エラー内容は

```
/usr/bin/env: ruby2.3: そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  

rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "    color: ": expected expression 
(e.g. 1px, bold), was ";"
(sass):1652
```

というのがみて取れました。

そこで質問なのですが、このエラー箇所がどこなのか全く見当がつかないのでどこを修正すればよいでしょうか？
cssの記述ミスなのだと思っているのですが（e.g. 1px, bold）なんて書いた記憶もありませんし、cssのファイルに１６５２行目もありません。

何かお気付きになられた方いましたら教えていただけると助かります。
また、問題箇所特定するために何をすればよいのかも助かります。
宜しくお願いしますm(._.)m

Answer (score 1):

`（e.g. 1px, bold）`は「例えば」という意味なので、実際にそういう記載があるという意味ではなさそうです。

> color: ": expected expression

Rails標準のSass（SCSS）を利用されているようなので、その記載が間違っていてコンパイルができていないようです。
`color`を使っている箇所に誤った記述がありそうなので、一度そのへんを見直すとなにか見つかるかもしれません。